# regex to find and convert inches?

Tags: regex, google-chrome-extension, replace

I'm new to the whole regex thing and I was hoping for some help with a little idea I had based on one of [xkcd's comics, substitution](https://xkcd.com/1288/).

How can I find anywhere in a page/section of text a `double`/`int` followed by a " OR '
So I can then convert to cm/m and replace it?

Matt Dickinson already did the leg work for the replacing, I just don't know how to find the numbers?

Thanks heaps in advance!
Matt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to know how to match the number you're looking for. This tutorial helps understand how to find a floating point number: http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html

It's pretty short and readable. I'd recommend reading it to try to learn more about what you're doing before trying anything below, but basically what you end up with from that to match a number is a regex that looks something like:

```
[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+
```

If you don't need the leading sign matching you can leave off the `[-+]?`, but it's optional anyway and will be good to have if it might be needed. I would replace the `[0-9]` with `\d` for brevity and (in my opinion) more readability. That gives

```
[-+]?\d*\.?\d+
```

You mentioned only wanting to match if it's followed by " or '. That's easily matched by `['"]` which then gives you:

```
[-+]?\d*\.?\d+['"]
```

Technically that meets what you requested, but you'll probably want to go a bit further.
For instance you may not want to match `"4.3"` or `5.2.4'`. To avoid these you might try to match only things that are at the beginning of the string or immediately follow a space. That can be signified by `(^|\s)`. But then that's included in your match which is probably undesirable. Getting around this problem would either require using a [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) or using submatches. Since not all languages support lookbehind I'll go down the route of submatches, but the specifics of how to get the appropriate submatch are language specific. To specify that you want to make a submatch you can simply surround the part of the expression you care about in (). This leads to something like

```
(^|\s)([-+]?\d*\.?\d+['"])
```

And you want what's in the second submatch. This can be improved by telling it you DON'T want to match that first subgroup by putting ?: inside the parens:

```
(?:^|\s)([-+]?\d*\.?\d+['"])
```

Now you want the first submatch. Getting the submatch is (as I mentioned) language specific. In JavaScript it would be `RegExp.$1` for the first submatch, `RegExp.$2` for the second and so on up to `RegExp.$9`.

Comment: This is fantastic thank you, thanks for the recommended reading too.

Comment: To match 5/16": (?:^|\s)([-+]?\d*\.?\/?\d+['"])